# Finding something in the TeX document from the PDF

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I am compiling a PDF (Adobe) using LaTeX (TexWorks) so I have the text document on one side of the screen and the PDF on the other, is there any way to select something on the PDF and it to find that text/command in the TeX document? I know that I could just highlight it and search the TeX document but if it is some symbol then this won't really work.

Comment: you  want one of these : http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=synctex

Answer (score 4):

As David Carlisle pointed out, you want synctex in TeXworks for this to work.

If you are on Mac OS you can <kbd>⌘</kbd>-Click (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on other OS's) anywhere in the TeXworks source file or the output and you will be moved to the corresponding point in the other document.